# Exploring getchar() function

Tags: c, c99, c89

I'm interested in C so I want to explore more on C especially C89 to see how this language changed over the time :). I bought "The C programming language" (2nd edition) by Denis Ritchie.

An example in the book brings me to a complicated situation about the getchar() function.

Example 1 which is my example after reading the book is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getchar();
    printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
    printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
}
```

The output of example 1 is:

```
a
'\n' character in c: 0
'\n' character in c: 0
```

In this case, the output doesn't show any new lines character in this input. HOWEVER, another example I try is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
    }
}
```

and the output of the code is:

```
a
'\n' character in c: 0
'\n' character in c: 1
```

I don't understand why the second example duplicates the printf() function and how it could read the '\n' character when it enters the loop. Meanwhile, the first example doesn't show anything relating to the '\n' character

Comment: It has to do with the input stream; the /n is still left in the input stream after the first call.

Comment: In the first code you're just checking that `a` twice, while in the second code, it's checking the `a`, and then the `\n`.

Comment: Mr. @Blaze, Can you explain to me how the memory works in both situations? Thanks you

Comment: Lundin's answer covers that nicely. The reason why it's not checking the `\n` in the first example is because you're not telling it to do so. `int c = getchar();` gets the `a` into `c`, and then you're checking that one twice. You never read that `\n`. You probably wanted another `c = getchar();` after the first print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your second example, i.e.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
}
```

and unroll the loop. It will become:

```
c = getchar();
if (c == EOF) return 0;
printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
c = getchar();
if (c == EOF) return 0;
printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
c = getchar();
if (c == EOF) return 0;
printf("\'\\n\' character in c: %d\n", c == '\n');
... and so on ...
```

Now compare this to your first version and you see that the difference is that the second example makes a `getchar` call between the `printf` while the first example only has one `getchar`call.

In other words - the first example only reads the character `'a'` while the second example first reads the `'a'` then reads the `'\n'` and then reads .... (whatever you type next)

Answer (score 2):

- You type `a` and press enter. The stdin buffer will then look like `a`, `\n`, two characters.
- First lap in the loop, `c` is of the value `'a'`, which is not equal to `'\n'`, output 0.
- Next lap in the loop, `c` is of the value `'\n'`, which is equal to `'\n'`, output 1.
- At end of input when `c` becomes `EOF`, the `printf` is never executed.

Comment: Thank you. But why does the first example not check the '\n' character?

Comment: It does not because you only request a character once. getchar() returns a single character at a time and any remaining characters are left on the input strean to be consumed by subsequent calls of getchar.

Answer (score 1):

You press enter after inputting `a`.

Thus your input stream will have "`a\n`".

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

Will read until it reaches `EOF`, thus it will read  `a` first then `\n`(enter).